# Running ionic serve I get this error : ''[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127)."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, ionic-framework

I am trying to run an ionic app on my Mac . when I run npm install to install the dependencies everything works without any problem .
but when I run ionic serve or ionic s I get this error

```
[ng] Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.
[ng] ****************************************************************************************
[ng] This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
[ng] It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
[ng]
[ng] DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
[ng] ****************************************************************************************
[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: readConfiguration is not a function
[ng] See "/private/tmp/ng-Ba9mkz/angular-errors.log" for further details.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 127).
```

as I searched for this error I found some solutions same as running `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev` but when I run this command I also get lots of errors which are mostly related to python however i have already installed the python

Comment: did you update your angular cli or something? you need to provide your Ionic and angular versioning either way.

Answer (score 0):

Delete defaultProject from angular.json file if it exists.

defaultProject has been deprecated.
See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11111

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35517916)